# Optimal way to create thumbnail gallery

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management, image-gallery

I am in the process of creating an app that shows a thumbnail view of image objects. *(The app is on iPad only)*.

The image objects show the following information with each one:

1. Image name
2. Price of photo
3. Favorite icon
4. A button for selecting the image (which the image is actually a button, with the background of the button being the image). Image is loaded from a URL.

I have gone about drawing these like so:

1. Created a custom view that contains the image, button, favorite icon, and price label.
2. When the container view is loaded, I draw all of these views out in a loop.
3. All of the views are drawn into a UIScrollView.

This is all works fine and dandy when the view is initially loaded in *Portrait* view.

I am trying to determine the best/optimal way to layout all of the views when the device is switched from Portrait to Landscape.

**The ways that I have thought to handle this is as follows:**

1. When the device is switched, completely wipe the view and reload everything.
2. As the views are loaded, add them to an holding array. When the device is rotated, cycle through the array and change the frames of each view.
3. In each view, have two properties. A property that holds their frame for portrait and landscape. When the device is rotated call reloadInputViews/ViewNeedsLayout/setNeedsLayout.

**My concerns:**

1. This would be really slow.
2. Adding all of these objects to an array would be hard on memory usage.
3. Would I loose the objects if they are not stored in an array when ViewNeedsLayout/setNeedsLayout/reloadInputViews is called.

-As always, that you for your help and your time is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [KKGridView](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/KKGridView) for this in the past and found it to be wonderfully flexible and responsive. It works with the same mechanics as a UITableView and is very efficient. I've just edited the cell drawing methods for my own purposes.

Your concerns are totally valid - this would be slow and prone to bugs in low-memory conditions if the view is offscreen. Luckily, KKGridView takes care of these issues for you.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if everything works out :) Feel free to ask me questions if you have trouble with the framework, too.

Comment: It works, but does not solve my problem. Thank you for the help.